# Integrating $\iint_D 2xy\exp(y^2)\,dxdy$ over the given region using polar coordinates.

Tags: integration

I got stuck integrating a double integral after evaluating the inner integral. the original question is as follows:

> [image: the question]

I have got this far in the solution:
[image: solution]

Can someone please help me solve the problem, I would really appreciate it,
Thank you very much

Comment: why $ pi/3$ ? it is the first quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$:  Replace $\frac{\pi}{3}$ by $\frac{\pi}{4}$, and integrate in the reverse order to get

$\displaystyle\hspace{.3 in} \int_1^2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}2r^3\sin\theta\cos\theta e^{r^2\sin^2\theta}d\theta dr$